# How to Revert form data to `initialValues`

Tags: redux-form

I have a form that allows the user to do a bunch of things like adding, deleting, modifying. The form takes a bunch of data from the state as `initialValues` and I have a requirement for an "Undo" button that reverts all the modifications back to how they were when `initialValues` was set.

Is there something built into redux-form that can do this? We're using v5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Reverting `redux-form` to the initial values is supported as an out of the box feature since version 6.*

It is easy to follow in the [Initialize from start](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/initializeFromState/) example from the `redux-form` documentation.

Since version 6.* the props passed by `redux-form` include a `reset` function the you simply need to call:

```
  let InitializeFromStateForm = props => {
    const { handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => load(data)}>Load Account</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
          <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Undo Changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I know you asked about version 5.3.3 - I've checked the docs for that version and can't see the reset function on the properties. It might be there somewhere - I started hitting compiler errors when I downgraded to that version of redux-form so didn't investigate too far. However, I have the feeling that without upgrading the the latest version, you will need to code the rollback yourself.

Comment: Hi David , thanks for replying! There is a `reset` function in 5.3.3 however it doesn't do what I want. As an example, in a deep form, deleting a row and calling `reset` doesn't return the deleted row. Does it do this in 6.*?

Comment: @JamieDixon I've just tried this (haven't done deep forms with this sort of reset before) - I smushed together two examples http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldArrays/  and http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/initializeFromState/ and it seems to work, but it could just be that my play example was different from yours.
Maybe post an example of your model and form, and I'll have a play - at least two people will look at it then!